Assistance Needed for Exporting Stacked Layers from Fiji to SolidWorks STEP File
I am currently working on a project that involves analyzing multiple aluminum layers, each with distinct properties. These layers are presently represented as separate layers within Fiji software. My objective is to stack all these layers to create a single volumetric model and export it as a STEP file, which I can then import into SolidWorks for finite element analysis (FEA).
I am seeking guidance on the best approach to achieve this task within Fiji. Specifically, I need assistance with the following points:
Merging the individual layers into a cohesive 3D volume.
Ensuring that the distinct properties of each layer are preserved in the process.
Exporting the resulting volumetric model as a STEP file compatible with SolidWorks.
I am seeking guidance on the best approach to achieve this task
